# Is good to use entities as controller arguments or controller returns?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, controller, asp.net-web-api2

First of all, sorry for my english.

I have the following doubt.

I'm creating a `WebAPI` with `.NET`, using `C#` and the `Entity Framework`. I was wondering if it's a good practice using an Entity as a controller argument, since the entity represents the model. I need to send all the data to the API and the `Entity Framework` generated classes seems to be a quick solution.

I was also wondering if returning an entity in a controller is something bad or not.

Comment: Generally speaking this is a bad idea - your entities are likely to have properties that you don't want users to be able to change but by using them as controller parameters, you expose all of their properties to the world. That and it is better to keep separation between controller parameters and entities in case you later have to map one action to two entities, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said previously, it's better to separate entities from objects exposed by your api.

Maybe later your apiService will need some other informations from another table and as @Ant P said always expose what you need not what you have, it can be private data like identity, foreign key, timestamp whatever.

This is why you should bind and compose a custom model, to which you can freely add data items as you need.

Comment: Ok. I won't use entities as controllers arguments or for retrieving data from the controller. Thanks ;)